# Pycharm mercurial push

Tags: mercurial, pycharm

Why is it when I select "Mercurial -> Push Changesets" or commit and push it will commit the changes but not push? If I then 'hg push' in the project directory via command prompt all changes get pushed nicely.

> The output in Pycharm will not contain any errors and stuff:
>
> hg.exe commit --logfile
>   C:\Users\=====.PyCharm20\system.hg4idea-commit.tmp core\views.py
>   reviewer\settings.py README core\distribute_email.py
>   reviewer\ldap_settings.py reviewer\settings_ldap.py core\utils.py
>   reviewer\settings_mail.py core\ldap_client.py No username found, using
>   '=====@homey' instead
>
> hg.exe branches

And that's all. It used to perform the pushes and display it's typical message - and has quite now - is there a way to get this back to work?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to fire a bug to the PyCharm public tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Provide all details there, especially attach the log (Help -> Reveal Log in ...).